# Is this type a valid "rank-2 bifunctor"?

Tags: haskell, functor, rank-n-types, bifunctor

The [rank2classes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes) package provides a version of [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes-1.4.1/docs/Rank2.html#t:Functor) for which the mapped functions seem to be natural transformations between type constructors.

Following that idea, here's a rank-2 version of [`Bifunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#t:Bifunctor):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
import Data.Kind

type Rank2Bifunctor :: ((Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> Type) -> Constraint
class Rank2Bifunctor b where
  rank2bimap ::
    (forall x. p x -> p' x) -> (forall x. q x -> q' x) -> b p q -> b p' q'
```

It seems clear that this type `Foo` can be given a `Rank2Bifunctor` instance:

```
data Foo f g = Foo (f Int) (g Int)

instance Rank2Bifunctor Foo where
    rank2bimap tleft tright (Foo f g) = Foo (tleft f) (tright g)
```

But what about this `Bar` type which nests `f` and `g`:

```
data Bar f g = Bar (f (g Int))
```

For starters, it seems that we would need to require `Functor p` in the signature of `rank2bimap`, to be able to transform the `g` inside the `f`.

Is `Bar` a valid "rank-2 bifunctor"?

Comment: The "barbies" package seems to have support for generically deriving rank-2 bifunctor classes: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.2.0/docs/Barbies.html#g:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed that's not an instance of your `Bifunctor`, since the lack of constraint allows you to pick a contravariant functor for `f` and then `rank2bimap` would amount roughly to implement `fmap` for `f`:

```
rank2bimap id :: (g ~> g') -> Bar f g -> Bar f g'  -- covariance of f, kinda (since Bar f g = f (g Int))

type f ~> f' = (forall x. f x -> f' x)
```

If you add the requirement that `f` and `g` (optional here) be functors, then you do get a bifunctor:

```
rank2bimap :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (f ~> f') -> (g ~> g') -> Bar f g -> Bar f' g'
```

In particular, to prove the bifunctor laws, you will need the free theorem of `f ~> f'`, assuming `f` and `f'` are functors, then `n :: f ~> f'` satisfies that for all `phi`, `fmap phi . n = n . fmap phi`.

Comment: E.g. set `g = Const Void, g' = Const (), f x ~= x -> Void`, then `g ~> g' ~= Void -> ()` and then `rank2bimap id ~:: (Void -> ()) -> (Void -> Void) -> () -> Void` deriving contradiction.

Comment: If we required both `p` and `q` to be (conventional) `Functor`s in the signature for `rank2bimap`, would the `Rank2Bifunctor` definition "make sense" from a category-theory perspective?

Comment: I added a bit to answer that.